# Form validation, form.valid() works but not form.validate()

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am having a form in my page and I am using the validation jquery plugin from here http://jqueryvalidation.org/

My form is:

```
 <form action="sendform.action" id="myform" method="post" name="myform">
  <fieldset>
       <label>Name:*</label> 
       <input id="cname" name="cname" type="text" value="" required/>
  </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
       <label>Email:*</label> 
       <input id="cmail" name="cmail" type="text" value="" required/>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
       <label>Phone:*</label> 
       <input id="cphone" name="cphone" type="text" value="" required/>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="submit-button">
    <a href="#">Send</a>
  </div>
 </form>
```

and my javascript:

```
$(".submit-button").click(function(){

    /*$("#myform").valid();*/
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            cphone: {
              required: true,
              number: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(this).submit();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that this thing is not working. I am not getting any error logs so I do not know what is wrong. Also if I use $("#myform").valid(); instead it works. 
So is only the .validate() that is not working. Anyone had an idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `validate()` function is the initialization method for tying the validator to your form and setting its rules. The `valid()` function executes the validation and returns true or false depending on if your form input values passed all of your rules.

Comment: ah thanks for this answer. So I keep both, and it works! Thanks a lot

Comment: You only have to call the `validate()` function once. So, I'd move it out of your `click()` event and put it with the rest of your view's initialization code.

Comment: Worth mentioning a few things...  1) `.validate()` method is _always required_ in order to initialize plugin.  2)  `.valid()` is an _optional_ method for the rare cases in which your form does not use a `type="submit"` input button.  3)  OP does not need his `submitHandler` callback function if all it contains is `.submit()`.  That's the _default_ behavior and everything will work the same without the `submitHandler`.